# Should the adjective "local" get the noun that it describes?

Tags: sentence-choice

Should the adjective "local" get the noun that it describes?

I mean to ask if I should say:

> We are local.

or we should say:

> We are local **+** people / residents etc.

Comment: Related: [Live Local](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2729/what-does-live-local-mean). Also related: [Eat Local](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4615/bumper-sticker-eat-local).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be idiomatic to say **We are locals** or **We're locals**.  It means "we live around *here*" or "we are from *this* place, we're not visitors".

**We're local** means "We live near *that place* [just mentioned]".

Comment: If you say "locals" it neans that the word ** 'local' ** can be a **noun**. But in cambridge dictionary it doesn't appear as a noun but as a adjective only. How can it be explain?

Comment: It can be explained by the simple fact that not every adjective which can be used as a noun will appear in every dictionary. See the definition for the noun **local** here: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/local  or here: https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/local

Answer (score 3):

I hear

> We are local residents.

A lot.

That being said, there are conversational situations where saying **we are local** works.

For example

> Nice to meet you, where are you from? 
>   I'm (I am) local.

Or

> I live locally.

As for

> We are local residents.

I imagine this being more of something you'd use in writing and less in conversation, but certainly it can be used anyway and is proper.

Example:

> We are local residents to the state of Idaho.
>
> As local residents, we find the statue to be most concerning and offensive.

**As I mentioned, there may be some different context where these sentences are used, but generally your idea will be conveyed with either of them.**

Answer (score 2):

The word *to be* is a copular verb (there's a few others).

This means the "object" of *to be X* can be an adjective.

Technically, X is a complement--objects are one type of complement, subject complements and predicate nominatives are two other types.  Copular verbs take complements of the other two types.

So, *we are local* - *local* is an adjective and is just fine.

*We are local people* is also fine - but *people* is only strictly necessary if you believe the listener/reader doesn't know *we* would mean *people* already.